# Адаптивная верстка

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, css

Начальник поставил задачу уменьшать динамически размер сайта, если ширина окна браузера меньше чем 1000 px. У меня есть идея - перебирать все элементы DOM поочередно и выставлять им необходимые размеры, но элементов реально много. Есть идея проще?

Comment: Вам поможет поиск по термину: резиновая верстка.

Comment: CSS Media Queries, либо резина, как предложили выше.

Comment: http://designnotfound.ru/about-media-queries/  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieru/archive/2011/01/25/the-css-corner-css3-media-queries.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   /* your styles */
}
```

Проще не придумаешь

Answer (score 0):

http://adapt.960.gs/